# Can I access the Facebook Audience Network API using a revokable token?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-audience-network

My company makes an ad network mediation product. We use each ad network's API to aggregate their stats on one dashboard. In order to do this for Facebook Audience Network, we currently have the developer give us their App ID and App Token, as per the [Reporting API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/reporting-api). As far as we can tell, though, the App Token isn't revokable, which makes some of our developers uneasy about sharing it.

Is there a way to access the Facebook Audience Network API using a revokable token, or a way to revoke an App Token?

Comment: According to the documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/app/app_insights : "A user access token with read_insights permission can retrieve metrics for all apps owned by this user".

Comment: And to add. They are uneasy because they should never never never share their app token with anyone

Comment: Thanks for your help @WizKid, I'm investigating using the read_insights permission. I didn't build this system, I'm just here to fix it.

Comment: @WizKid Ok, just `read_insights` as a permission is enough like you suggested. Do you want to make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation at developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/app/… : "A user access token with read_insights permission can retrieve metrics for all apps owned by this user".

So just have the user login to your app and grant read_insights to your app.